# How to access the difficulty of an older block from within a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, blocks, difficulty

Is it possible to access properties of an older block from within a **smart contract** (e.g. difficulty, timestamp etc.)?

Comment: No, the only property available is the block hashes from the previous 255 blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ismael said in a comment it's not possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can access block hashes of the previous 256 blocks within a smart contract. But if you want other properties (e.g. difficulty, timestamp etc) of older blocks, you can use methods such as `web3.eth.getBlock()` from web3.js.

See:

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#special-variables-and-functions

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html